# jQuery Listview changing list item color

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview

I suck so hard at javascript - I can't figure out how to change the background color of a list item in a jquery listview...

```
var parent = document.getElementById('listDiv');

var listview = document.createElement('ul');
listview.setAttribute('id', 'listView');

parent.appendChild(listview);
var listItem = document.createElement('li');
listItem.setAttribute('id', 'temp');
var itemLink = document.createElement('a');
itemLink.setAttribute('href', '#');
itemLink.innerHTML = "HEYY MAN";

listItem.appendChild(itemLink);
listview.appendChild(listItem);


$('#listView').listview().listview('refresh');

//I NEED DIS SHIT TO WORK
$('#listView').on('click', 'li', function(){
    $('#temp').css('background-color','green');   
});
```

Everything is displayed correctly, and you can play around with it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kburbach/t7NKL/), but either the 'click' functionality or the background color change is not working correctly. Can someone lend a helping hand?

Comment: your question content was actually a solution for my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of jQuery you're using (1.6.4) doesn't support the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function, it was only introduced in version 1.7. I've replaced it with [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to get it working temporarily:

```
$('#listView').bind('click', 'li', function(){
    $('#temp').css('background','green');   
});
```

`background-color` was changed to just `background` in order to override the jQuery Mobile styling.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/q3vfh/3/

However, if you're not tied to that version of jQuery then I'd recommend using the code from this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q3vfh/2/ - it uses jQuery 2.0.2 and jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 and allows you to use `.on()`.

Comment: thanks man, i spent way too long trying to figure out that problem. I'm not tied to that version so I will be making the switch!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#listView').delegate('li','click', function(){
$(this).css({background: '#6495ED'})   
});
```